# InternetExplorer.Application DOM element attributes

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, attributes, element

I am creating a program for DOM manipulation and I am stuck at reading element attributes.

The problem is that InternetExplorer.Application returns all attributes despite the fact if an attribute is set or not.

For example: InternetExplorer.Application.Document.DocumentElement.Attributes.Length returns 161.

I could iterate through all the attributes and check whether it is null or not but this is overload considering there is one or two attributes set out of 161.

I expect InternetExplorer.Application to return list of attributes which have value assigned just like it does in F12 in IE.

Can anyone help me out here please?

Thank you.

Comment: You can iterate through the list checking whether the element is null or not and push to another list, but what are you trying to achieve?what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I can iterate throught the list of attributes and check whether getAttribute returns null or not, however this takes a lot of time.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve element attributes and its values faster. Iterating through all possible attributes (161) and checking whether it is set or not is really slow.

Comment: Code Review stack exchange might be a better place to ask questions about performance on working code.